# Could not push .dll file into GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I have faced the error

> remote: Hello there! We have restricted the binary files (.exe, .dll, .zip, .7z, .deb, .cab, .gz, .pkg, .iso) that are pushed into GitLab.

while try to push the .dll file into GitLab. 
I tried to remove the .dll file type from the git ignore file list but i could not find the document gitignore_global.txt which is directory was represented in,
Gitlab: **Tools->Options->Git tab->Edit file.**

Kindly let me know If the document was not present then where from the ignore-able list was get and how can i skip .dll files from those list.

Comment: I can commit and push all scripts and it goes fine but when I try to push .dll commits it freezes at pushing stage.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running your own server (and the admins, if not you, change the push rules), you won't be able to push any of those file types. Those 9 are selected since generally those are very large files and shouldn't be stored in git.

If you run your own Gitlab server though, and absolutely need to store the .dll file in git, you can adjust the push rules in the Admin area. See the docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html#enabling-push-rules